# How to hide it?

Tags: boot, xubuntu

How do I hide this:

[image]

and I'd also like to hide:

[image: http://pics.tinypic.pl/i/00704/nxpoiiw2gjcw.jpeg]

My system is Xubuntu 15.04 64 bit.

`/etc/default/grub`:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1280x1024

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Is the first always black, even on other backgrounds? (as in failed pixels) or is the white dash blinking as a cursor?

Comment: Please clarify what happens when and if this is a new installation.

Comment: Xubuntu was installed a few days ago - this happens after installing nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix the first problem, but the second should be fixed with updating lines to look like this in /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=quiet   #Don't show Ubuntu bootup text
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty12" #Don't show kernel text
```

After that you will have to run `sudo update-grub` to push the updates to grub.

Comment: Doesn't work - this destroys plymouth screen.